# Why does start-slave.sh require master URL?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-standalone

I'm wondering why the client, using `apache-spark/sbin/start-slave.sh <master's URL>` has to indicate this `master's URL`, since the master already indicates it in : `apache-spark/sbin/start-master.sh --master spark://my-master:7077e.g.` ?

Is it because the client must wait for the master to receive the `submit` sent by the master ? If yes : then why the master must specify `--master spark://....` in its `submit` ?

Comment: That's because you can connect to any master you want, plus that's not the only way to specify the default master. I advise you to read here http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

`start-slave.sh <master's URL>` starts a standalone Worker (formerly a slave) that the standalone Master available at `<master's URL>` uses to offer resources to Spark applications.

Standalone Master manages workers and it's workers to register themselves with a master and give CPU and memory for resource offering.

From [Starting a Cluster Manually](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html#starting-a-cluster-manually):

> You can start a standalone master server by executing:
>
> `./sbin/start-master.sh`
>
> Once started, the master will print out a spark://HOST:PORT URL for itself, which you can use to connect workers to it, or pass as the “master” argument to SparkContext. You can also find this URL on the master’s web UI, which is http://localhost:8080 by default.
>
> Similarly, you can start one or more workers and connect them to the master via:
>
> `./sbin/start-slave.sh <master-spark-URL>`

---

> since the master already indicates it in : apache-spark/sbin/start-master.sh --master spark://my-master:7077

You can specify the URL of the standalone Master that defaults to `spark://my-master:7077`, but that's not announced on the network so anyone could know the URL (unless specified on command line).

> why the master must specify --master spark://.... in its submit

It does not. Standalone Master and submit are different "tools", i.e. the former is a cluster manager for Spark applications while the latter is to submit Spark applications to a cluster manager for execution (that could be on any of the three supported cluster managers: Spark Standalone, Apache Mesos and Hadoop YARN).

See [Submitting Applications](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html).